# How to move a number of columns in a matrix to the right most in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have an mxn matrix A. Suppose I have a list (or a vector) P of i elements where each element of P indicates the number of a column in A. I need to move all the columns indicated by P to the right most of A; for instance the the columns indicated in the first and the i'th elements in P will become the (n-i)'th and the n'th column of A respectively.

Hope my statement is clear, let me know if there is any ambiguity.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get the columns 3,5,7 to the right, first `c` is constructed which indicates the new order of columns. Then the columns are indexed using `c` which reorders them.

```
>> M=magic(10);
>> c=[3,5,7];
>> c=[setdiff(1:size(M,2),c),c]

c =

  Columns 1 through 9

     1     2     4     6     8     9    10     3     5

  Column 10

     7

>> M=M(:,c);
```

Comment: This is the way to go!